# How to click in an application at particular location(x,y) (Application is running in background )?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, sikuli, citrix

I want automate **citrix application** which can be accessed with the help of chrome browser. So, I am using **selenium web-driver** to open application in browser. And, the main thing is that I want to automate it in **headless mode**(Browser will run in background).

I would like to achieve following task :
- As we can't inspect HTML element in citrix application, so all what we have is image, which can be automate through image detection.

So, my first question is that, is it possible to automate **citrix application in background** (i.e. without displaying on monitor) ???

-If it is possible then, I can use selenium to capture screenshot of application even in background.
- And with the help of **sikuli**, I can find location of object where I have to perform action such as click, type and hover.

Now, another question is that How to click on particular location in the application which is running in background ????

I have tried following but none of them worked in my case :

1.Robot class (Failed due to : does not work in background )

2. Selenium Action class(Failed due to : require Web-element )
3. javascriptexecutor (Failed due to : require Web-element )

Does anyone know, how this can be done ??

Thank you !!!

Comment: Sikuli won't be able to access the background browser

Comment: Hi @Eugene, thanks for the response. Yes, we can't use sikuli for background automation but with the help of sikuli we can get  location of object where we have to click. So, my query is if you know where you have to click on a particular location and the application is running in background. So is there any way, we can do it ??